# React re-rendering parts of page after onChange/onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm about to finish my dissertation but just encountered a major bug that I've not come across before. I basically have a component that renders sprints (project management) and the user stories tied to it. Now the way you can add sprints is by typing something into a textbox or selecting a user story from the backlog from a dropdown. I also have giving the option to edit and delete a story from a sprint.

The main problem here is that every time I type something in the textbox for a user story or make a selection from the dropdown or even try to edit or delete a user story the page refreshes on me. I am clueless as to why it's doing this since I've not really changed anything in this component for a while and it's randomly started doing this. (renderSprints method)

**My component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { Dropdown, Button, NavItem, Tabs, Tab, Row, Input, Modal, Icon } from 'react-materialize';
import logo from '../images/scrumtastic_logo_white.png';
import axios from 'axios';
import { BASE_URL } from '../constants';
import moment from 'moment';
import Toast from './Toast';
import '../App.css';

class SprintView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            'userId': '',
            'email': '',
            'userEmail': '',
            'token': '',
            'projectId': '',
            'users': [],
            'sprints': [],
            'features': [],
            'stories': [],
            'backlogStories': [],
            'sprintStartDate': '',
            'sprintEndDate': '',
            'storyDesc': '',
            'newStoryDesc': '',
            'clickedStory': '',
            'storyEditingMode': false,
            'userStoryCheck': false,
            'selectValue': '',
            'sprintId': '',
            'error': [],
            'origStories': []
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
       let email = localStorage.getItem('email');
       let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
       let userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
       let projectId = localStorage.getItem('projectId');
       let projectName = localStorage.getItem('projectName');
       let stories = localStorage.getItem('stories');
       let origStories = localStorage.getItem('backlogStories');
       this.setState({'token': token, 'userId': userId, 'projectId': projectId, 'projectName': projectName, 'email': email, 'backlogStories': stories, 'origStories': origStories});

        axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
        axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/projects/${projectId}/users`)
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({'users': data.data[0].users})
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({error});
            })  
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const token = 'Bearer ' + this.state.token
        const projectId = this.state.projectId;

        axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
        axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/projects/${projectId}/sprints`)
            .then((data) => {
                let projectSprints = [];
                data.data[0].sprints.forEach((sprint) => {
                    projectSprints.push(sprint);
                })
                this.setState({'sprints': projectSprints});
                this.getStories(projectSprints);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({error});
            }) 
    }

    saveStoriesToStorage() {
        localStorage.setItem('stories', this.state.stories);
        localStorage.setItem('sprintId', this.state.sprintId);
    }

    renderUsers() {

        return (
            <ul className="collection">
            {
            this.state.users.map(user => {
                    return (
                        <li key={user.id} className="collection-item"><div style={{float: 'left', position: 'relative', top: '-5px'}}><Icon small>account_box</Icon></div>{user.email}</li>
                    )  
            })
            }
            </ul>
        )
    }

    getStories(projectSprints) {
        const token = 'Bearer ' + this.state.token;
        let stateStories = [];

        projectSprints.forEach(sprint => {
            axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
            axios.get(BASE_URL + '/sprints/' + sprint.id + '/stories')
                .then((data) => {

                    let sprintStories = [];
                    data.data[0].stories.forEach((story) => {
                        sprintStories.push(story);
                    })
                    sprintStories.forEach(story => {
                        stateStories.push(story);
                    })
                    this.setState({'stories': stateStories});

                        this.getBacklogStories();
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.setState({error});
                }) 
        })
    }

    getBacklogStories() {
        const token = 'Bearer ' + this.state.token
        const projectId = this.state.projectId;

        axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token

        axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/projects/${projectId}/stories`)
            .then((data) => {
                let projectStories = [];
                data.data[0].stories.forEach((story) => {
                    projectStories.push(story);
                })
                this.setState({'backlogStories': projectStories});
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({error});
            }) 
    }

    logOut() {
        const token = 'Bearer ' + this.state.token;

        axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
        axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/logout`, {
            'email': this.state.email,
        })
            .then((data) => {
                if(data.status === 200) {
                    localStorage.removeItem('token')
                    localStorage.removeItem('email')
                    let t = new Toast("Succesfully logged out!", 2500)
                    t.Render(); 
                    setTimeout(() => {browserHistory.push('/signin')}, 2500)
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({error});
            }) 
    }

    createStory(sprintId) {
        let stories = this.state.stories;

        const token = 'Bearer ' + this.state.token;

        axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
        axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/sprintstories`, {
            'description': this.state.storyDesc,
            'sprint_id': sprintId,
            'project_id': this.state.projectId
        })
            .then((data) => {
                data.data.pivot = { 'sprint_id': sprintId, 'story_id': data.data.id};
                stories.push(data.data);
                this.setState({'stories': stories});
                this.forceUpdate();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({error});
            }) 
    }

    handleCheck() {
        this.setState({'userStoryCheck': !this.state.userStoryCheck});
    }

    createStorySelect(sprintId) {
        const backlogStories = this.state.stories;
        if (backlogStories) {
            let items = [];
            for(let i = 0; i < backlogStories.length; i++) {
                items.push(<NavItem key={i} value={backlogStories[i].description} onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this, backlogStories[i].id, sprintId)}>{backlogStories[i].description}</NavItem>);
            }

            return items;
        }
    }

    addStoryToSprint(storyId, sprintId) {
        const token = 'Bearer ' + this.state.token;
        let stories = this.state.stories;

        axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
        axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/storestorypivot`, {
            'sprint_id': sprintId,
            'story_id': storyId
        })
            .then((data) => {
                data.data.pivot = { 'sprint_id': sprintId, 'story_id': data.data.id};
                stories.push(data.data);
                this.setState({'stories': stories});
                this.forceUpdate();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({error});
            })        
    }

    renderErrors() {
        let errors = [];
        if(this.state.error.response && this.state.error.response.data) {
            const errorResp = this.state.error.response.data.error;
            if (typeof errorResp === "string") {
                errors.push(<p className="errorMessage" key={"error_" + 1}>{errorResp}</p>)
            } else {
                for (let key in errorResp) {
                    errors.push(<p className="errorMessage" key={"error_" + key}>{errorResp[key]}</p>)
                }
            }
        }
        return <div className="center-align">{errors}</div>
    }

    handleChange(storyId, sprintId) {
        this.addStoryToSprint(storyId, sprintId);
    }

    goToTasks(sprintId) {
        localStorage.setItem('sprintId', sprintId);
        browserHistory.push('/list');
    }

    addUser() {
        const token = 'Bearer ' + this.state.token;
        let users = this.state.users;

        axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
        axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/attachuser`, {
            'email': this.state.userEmail,
            'project_id': this.state.projectId
        })
            .then((data) => {
                users.push(data.data[0]);
                this.setState({users: users})
                let userModal = document.getElementById('userModal');
                let userModalOverlay = document.getElementById('materialize-modal-overlay-1');
                userModal.style.display = 'none';
                userModalOverlay.style.display = 'none';
                let t = new Toast(this.state.userEmail + " added to project!", 2500)
                t.Render(); 
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({error});
            })   
    }

    sprintIdToStorage(sprintId) {
        this.setState({sprintId: sprintId})
    }

    editStory(storyId, storyDescription) {

        if(this.state.storyEditingMode === true) {
            const token = 'Bearer ' + this.state.token;
            let newStoryDesc = this.state.newStoryDesc;
            let stories = this.state.stories;

            if(this.state.storyDesc) {
                newStoryDesc = this.state.storyDesc
            }

            axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
            axios.put(`${BASE_URL}/stories/${storyId}`, {
                'description': newStoryDesc
            })
                .then((data) => {
                    for (var i=0; i < stories.length; i++) {
                        if (stories[i].id === storyId) {
                            stories[i].description = newStoryDesc;
                            this.setState({'storyDesc': ''});
                            this.setState({'stories': stories});
                        }
                    }  
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.setState({error});
                }) 
        } 
        else {
            this.setState({'newStoryDesc': storyDescription});
        }

        if(storyId) {
            this.setState({'clickedStory': storyId});
        }
        this.setState({'storyEditingMode': !this.state.storyEditingMode});
    }

    deleteStory(storyId) {
        let stories = this.state.stories;
        const token = 'Bearer ' + this.state.token;

        axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
        axios.delete(`${BASE_URL}/stories/${storyId}`)
            .then((data) => {
                this.searchAndDeleteStoryFromState(storyId, stories);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({error});
            }) 
    }

    searchAndDeleteStoryFromState(keyName, array) {
        for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].id === keyName) {
                delete array[i]
                this.setState({'stories': array});
            }
        }    
    }

    renderSprints() {
        const sprints = this.state.sprints;
        const stories = this.state.stories;

        return (
            <div className="row">
                {this.state.sprints.length === 0 ? <p style={{marginLeft: '10px'}} className="sprint-message waves-effect waves-light teal lighten-2">Seems like you need to add some sprints</p> : null }
                <Tabs className='tab-demo z-depth-1'>
                {
                    sprints.map(sprint => {
                        return (
                            <Tab key={sprint.id} title={sprint.name}>

                                <h3>{moment(sprint.start_date).format("MMM Do YY")} - {moment(sprint.end_date).format("MMM Do YY")}</h3>
                                {
                                    stories.map((story, key) => {
                                        if(story.pivot.sprint_id === sprint.id) {
                                            return (
                                                <ul key={key} className="collection with-header">
                                                {
                                                    <li key={key+1} className="collection-item">
                                                    {
                                                        (!this.state.storyEditingMode && (this.state.clickedStory === null)) || (!this.state.storyEditingMode && (this.state.clickedStory === story.id)) || (!this.state.storyEditingMode && (this.state.clickedStory !== story.id)) || (this.state.storyEditingMode && (this.state.clickedStory !== story.id)) ?
                                                        <div>
                                                            <div style={{float: 'left', position: 'relative', top: '-5px'}}><Icon small>label_outline</Icon></div> {story.description}
                                                            <a onClick={this.deleteStory.bind(this, story.id)} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}><i className="material-icons small" style={{color: '#a6262c', float: 'right'}}>delete_forever</i></a>
                                                            <a onClick={this.editStory.bind(this, story.id, story.description)} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}><i className="material-icons small" style={{color: '#2633a6', float: 'right'}}>mode_edit</i></a>
                                                        </div>
                                                        :
                                                        <div className="row">
                                                            <div className="input-field col s8">
                                                                <input 
                                                                    type="text"
                                                                    placeholder={story.description}
                                                                    onChange={event => this.setState({storyDesc:event.target.value})}
                                                                    onKeyPress={event => {
                                                                    if(event.key === "Enter") {
                                                                            this.editStory(story.id, null);
                                                                        }
                                                                    }}
                                                                />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <a onClick={() => {this.editStory(story.id, null)}} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}><i className="material-icons small" style={{color: '#2633a6', float: 'right'}}>mode_edit</i></a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    }
                                                    </li>
                                                }
                                                </ul>
                                            )
                                        }

                                    })
                                }

                                { !this.state.userStoryCheck ?
                                    <div>
                                    <input 
                                        className="validate"
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="Add Your User Story"
                                        onChange={event => this.setState({storyDesc:event.target.value})}
                                        onKeyPress={event => {
                                        if(event.key === "Enter") {
                                                this.createStory(sprint.id);
                                            }
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <p>
                                        <input type="checkbox" className="filled-in" id={sprint.id} onClick={this.handleCheck.bind(this)} />
                                            <label htmlFor={sprint.id}>Check to select a User Story</label>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                :
                                <div>
                                    <Dropdown trigger={
                                        <Button defaultValue={this.state.selectValue} onChange={this.handleChange}>Select User Story</Button>
                                        }>
                                        {this.createStorySelect(sprint.id)}
                                    </Dropdown>
                                    <p>
                                    <input type="checkbox" className="filled-in" id={sprint.id} onClick={this.handleCheck.bind(this)} />
                                        <label htmlFor={sprint.id}>Check to manually add a User Story</label>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                }
                                <a 
                                    className="waves-effect waves-light btn-large"
                                    onClick={() => this.goToTasks(sprint.id)}
                                >
                                Go To Sprint Board
                                </a>
                            </Tab>
                        )
                    })
                }
                </Tabs>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="teal lighten-3">
                    <div className="nav-wrapper">
                    <a className="brand-logo" href="/"><img className="nav-logo" src={logo} alt="logo"/></a>
                        <ul id="nav-mobile" className="left hide-on-med-and-down" style={{paddingLeft: '180px'}}>
                            <li><a href="/">Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/projects">Backlog</a></li>
                            <li><a onClick={this.saveStoriesToStorage.bind(this)} href="/list">Tasks</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul id="nav-mobile" className="right hide-on-med-and-down" style={{marginRight: '10px'}}>
                            <i className="material-icons" style={{height: 'inherit', lineHeight: 'inherit', float: 'left', margin: '0 30px 0 0', width: '2px'}}>perm_identity</i>
                            <Dropdown trigger={
                                <Button style={{display: 'inline'}}>{this.state.email}</Button>
                                }>
                                <NavItem onClick={this.logOut.bind(this)}><span><span id="nav-icon"><Icon large>input</Icon></span><span style={{position: 'relative', fontSize: '2.5rem', top: '15px', left: '10px', float: 'left'}}>Log Out</span></span></NavItem>
                                <NavItem divider />
                            </Dropdown>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s2" />
                    <div className="col s8">
                        <h2 style={{color: '#26a69a'}}>{this.state.projectName}: Sprints</h2>
                        <Modal id="sprintModal" trigger={<Button style={{float: 'right', position: 'relative', top: '-70px'}}><Icon small>
                                playlist_add
                            </Icon><span style={{position: 'relative', top: '-4px', marginLeft: '5px'}}>Add Sprint</span></Button>}>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col s2" />
                            <div className="col s7">
                                <h3 style={{paddingLeft: '89px'}}>Add Sprint</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col s3" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col s3" />
                            <div className="col s6">
                            <Row>
                                <Input style={{width: '175px'}} name='on' type='date' placeholder="Start Date" onChange={event => this.setState({sprintStartDate:event.target.value})} />
                                <Input style={{width: '175px'}} name='on' type='date' placeholder="End Date" onChange={event => this.setState({sprintEndDate:event.target.value})} />
                                <Button
                                    onClick={() => this.addSprint()}
                                >
                                    Add Sprint
                                </Button>
                            </Row>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col s3" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col s3" />
                            <div className="col s6">
                                {this.renderErrors()}
                            </div>
                            <div className="col s3" />
                        </div>
                        </Modal>
                        <Modal id="userModal" trigger={<Button style={{float: 'right', position: 'relative', top: '-70px', marginRight: '15px'}}>
                            <Icon small>
                                account_box
                            </Icon><span style={{position: 'relative', top: '-4px', marginLeft: '5px'}}>Add User</span></Button>}>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col s2" />
                            <div className="col s7">
                                <h3 style={{paddingLeft: '25px'}}>Add User</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col s3" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col s2" />
                            <div className="col s1" style={{paddingTop: '25px', paddingLeft: '40px'}}>
                                <Icon small>
                                email    
                                </Icon>
                            </div>
                            <div className="input-field inline col s6">
                                <input 
                                    className="validate"
                                    id="user"
                                    type="email"
                                    defaultValue=""
                                    onChange={event => this.setState({userEmail:event.target.value})}
                                    onKeyPress={event => {
                                    if(event.key === "Enter") {
                                            this.addUser();
                                        }
                                    }}
                                />
                                <label htmlFor="user">Enter User Email</label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col s3" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col s3" />
                            <div className="col s6">
                                {this.renderErrors()}
                            </div>
                            <div className="col s3" />
                        </div>
                        </Modal>
                        {this.renderSprints()}
                        <div className="row">
                            { this.renderErrors() }
                        </div>
                        <h2 style={{color: '#26a69a'}}>Contributors</h2>
                        <div className="row">
                            {this.renderUsers()}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col s2" />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SprintView;
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated a lot since this project is due in a couple days, thanks!

Comment: When you say page refreshes, do you mean a true reload of the page or react is re-rendering and wiping the state?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: Can you confirm that all your axios calls are completed during the mounting?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `this.setState()` will always force a component to re-render.

Another way of doing it would be `this.forceUpdate()`

Good luck!

Comment: I have not seen this type of behaviour in any other of my components, I know this.setState() will make a component re-render, I use the same type of code in two other components and I don't have the problem there. Any type of handleChange or handleClick function didn't change anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

First off - consider splitting your component up into smaller components for readability

I believe your issue is the Button action you are using throughout your component. The default button action is to submit the form which causes the page to refresh. If you don't want this to occur, you need to take this into account within all your functions:

```
handleClick(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   console.log("No refresh!");
}
```

Comment: Tried e.preventDefault/stopPropagation in various functions and didn't have any effect sadly.

Comment: man - I was almost certain that was the issue... where is the `addSprint()` function located? I didn't see that in the code, yet, it is called in the render method

Comment: This wrong because if you look at the react-materialize source code, `Button`, is not a button, but an `<a>` wrapped around a `<div>`. This is why the typical preventDefault/stopPropagation logic doesn't work here.